# How to unbind jQuery keydown (shift key)?

Tags: jquery

Try to build some code to highlight records in a tabular table by holding down the shift key to start the selection and left (if you're right handed) mouse click to end the selection.

I've used a global variable to stop the selection in the mousedown event and the code only works if the shift key is pressed once and released immediately. However, if the shift key is held down and release at the end of the selection it causes side effect as the mouse button is clicked again. (i.e. pressed one ok, holding down introduces side effects)

I have code to bind (not sure the term binding here is correct) the keydown event and don't how to unbind/remove it in another event - mousedown.

```
var C_MARKER_INIT_VAL      = "_INIT_";
var C_MAIN_MOUSE_BUTTON    = 1;      // i.e. left button for the right handed person


$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.shiftKey) {
    gBeginMarker = $("*:focus").attr('id');
  }
});
```

I attempt to remove this in the mousedown event as follow:

```
$(document).mousedown(function(event) {
  if (event.which===C_MAIN_MOUSE_BUTTON && gBeginMarker && gBeginMarker != C_MARKER_INIT_VAL) {
    var e = event || window.event;

            // do some stuff


            // Re-initialize global variable to prevent this code block from firing again
    gBeginMarker = C_MARKER_INIT_VAL;
  }
});
```

What is the difference between the shift key be pressed once and being held down (say a few seconds)?

Appreciate any help in removing the shift key event after the mouse is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [namespace](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) your events. i.e., `$(document).on('keydown.toRemove', function(e){`.
2. Unbind the event with `$(document).off('keydown.toRemove');`. ([`.off` docs](http://api.jquery.com/off/))